# I am getting this error when i pass the path of the image to the display function using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

```
import cv2

def display(newphoto):
    photo = cv2.imread(newphoto)
    cv2.imshow('my feed', photo)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

newphoto = input()
display(newphoto)
```

Here's the error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xr4y3u3_\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

I don't know why this code is showing `Assertion failed` and throwing Error in `imshow` function.

Comment: make sure image path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"error: (-215)" means that an assertion failed. In this case, cv::imshow asserts that the given image is non-empty and if the file does not exist, then cv2.imread() will return None; it does not raise an exception.

it should be something like

```
img = cv2.imread('no-such-file.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

not just

```
photo=cv2.imread(newphoto)
```

make sure that the file actually exists at the specified path. If it does, it might be that the image is corrupted, or is an empty image.
(new photo) is just not a location of a image is it .

Comment: the image  is in the right path when i pass direct input it is working but when i pass it through function it fails